# Apache server as a proxy using iptables

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, proxy, raspberry-pi, iptables

I want to accomplish the following: I want to show a task bar on top of all websites I request from my notebook. On this bar I display various information.

I have a Raspberry Pi in my network which I configured as a gateway on my notebook. So all the traffic from my notebook passes the raspberry. On the raspberry I installed an Apache server with two VirtualHosts. One is a local webserver listening on port *80*. For the other one, listening on port *8126*, I have the following rules:

1. If no *special* parameter is set in the request, I redirect the request to a local page (with the original requested URI as a parameter). On this page I have an iframe in which I show the originally requested page, using the URI I read out from the parameters. To avoid having an endless loop I add the *special* parameter to the link in the iframe. This part works fine.
2. If the *special* parameter is not set (since the page should be display in the iframe), I redirect the request to the originally requested page using *mod_rewrite* again. This redirecting seems to cause the problems.

So here is some code of what I am doing:
I redirect all traffic on port *80* to port *8126* using iptables. *192.168.1.1* is the IP address of my raspberry which I use since I can not redirect to the loopback interface in the *PREROUTING* phase. I do this with the following iptables-rule:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp 80 -j DNAT 192.168.1.1:8126`

I boiled down my problem to the following VirtualHost configuration for the Apache server, where I simply redirect all requests to an external website:

```
<VirtualHost *:8126>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://example.com/ [P]
        ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

On my notebook I set the gateway to *192.168.1.1*, open my Chrome browser and send an HTTP request to e.g. *test.com*. I would expect to get redirected to *example.com*. But I receive an error message saying

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Does anybody have an idea how I could solve this? I am free for completely different approaches solving my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your iptables rule creates a loop so requests FROM the proxy are sent again to himself.

You should avoid that by excluding Proxy source IP from rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -s ! <Your proxy IP> -p tcp 80 -j DNAT 192.168.1.1:8126
```